# Inject code with nested quotes and apostrophes?

Tags: javascript, php, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I have this code in my PHP file.

```
var my_edit = "<div title='Edit record: "+ rowObject['my_id'] +"' 
 onclick=\"jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('editGridRow', '" + options.rowId + "',
 { onInitializeForm : $upload } );\" >Edit</div>";
```

the variable **$upload** is something like this:

```
$upload = <<<UPLOAD

   function (formid) {

      alert('I am in UPLOAD!');
      $("#cusom_id", formid).button();
      // other code with many quotes and apostrophes

   }

UPLOAD;
```

My code is not working, since there are errors with quotes and apostrophes.

What would be a correct way to inject my **$upload** function into the first snipped of code i posted above?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your quotes, and you should be able to use [addslashes()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)

```
$upload = <<<UPLOAD
function (formid) {
  alert('I am in UPLOAD!');
  $("#cusom_id", formid).button();
  // other code with many quotes and apostrophes
}
UPLOAD;
$upload = addslashes($upload);
// now you can embed it in the string my_edit.
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, To be honest! This ain't gonna work properly and this is not a good practice..

I wonder why are you using PHP variable to call javascript function in $upload when you can directly access it through javascript function itself!

for example...

```
function myUpload (formid) {

  alert('I am in UPLOAD!');
  $("#cusom_id", formid).button();
  // other code with many quotes and apostrophes
```

}

```
 var my_edit = "<div title='Edit record: "+ rowObject['my_id'] +"'onclick=\"jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('editGridRow','" + options.rowId + "', {onInitializeForm : myUpload(formid) } );\" >Edit</div>";
```

Comment: Hello, I appreciate your reply, although this code is part of a complex PHP + MySQL + Javascript project. the quoted code is part of a PHP file